# Can I insert the string generated by openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() into a CHAR column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string

In PHP, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() generates a random "string of bytes." For example, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10) returns a 10-byte random string that is displayed like that: `9�,cy���`

Now let's say I have a table `mytable` with `mycolumn` of type CHAR(10).

Can I do

```
$string = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10);
$query = 'INSERT INTO mytable WHERE mycolumn=' . $string;
$response = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

or do I have to convert it with bin2hex() or base64_encode()?

Comment: did you tried ??? is there any issue??

Comment: Yes you have to do so as well.